# Reflection, MethodInfo, GetMethods, include only methods only added by me

Tags: c#

I am new to C#.

I wrote an application which uses reflection to iterate through all methods of selected object and runs it.

The problem is that `MethodInfo[] methodInfos = typeof(ClassWithManyMethods).GetMethods();` returns also methods like `ToString`, `GetType` and I would like to include only methods declared specifically for my class.

Please have a look at my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Reflection;


namespace Reflection4
{
    class ClassWithManyMethods
    {
    public void a()
    {
        Console.Write('a');
    }

    public void b()
    {
        Console.Write('b');
    }

    public void c()
    {
        Console.Write('c');
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // get all public static methods of MyClass type
        MethodInfo[] methodInfos = typeof(ClassWithManyMethods).GetMethods();
        ClassWithManyMethods myObject = new ClassWithManyMethods();

        foreach (MethodInfo methodInfo in methodInfos)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(methodInfo.Name);
            methodInfo.Invoke(myObject, null); //problem here!
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Textbook example of a comment that enhances your code. `// get all public static methods of MyClass type`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will need to specify all the binding flags you need, in your case:

```
BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly
BindingFlags.Public
BindingFlags.Instance
```

so:

```
MethodInfo[] methodInfos = typeof(ClassWithManyMethods)
    .GetMethods(BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
```

Answer (score 2):

Add [DeclaredOnly](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/vstudio/system.reflection.bindingflags.aspx) to the BindingFlags flag.

```
typeof(ClassWithManyMethods).GetMethods(BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly | ...)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this overloaded of [`GetMethods`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.getmethods.aspx):

```
var result = typeof(ClassWithManyMethods).GetMethods(BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly);
```

> DeclaredOnly  Specifies that only members declared at the level of the
>   supplied type's hierarchy should be considered. Inherited members are
>   not considered.